# Unable to deploy code to google cloud environment

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven-3, google-cloud-endpoints, eclipse-luna

I am using eclipse Luna + maven 3.2 . I have developed small application and trying to move to console.developers.google.com using mvn:appengine:devserver .
    But i am getting build failure . below is the error .

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building helloworld 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:devserver (default-cli) > package @ helloworld >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory F:\googleAppEngine\helloworld\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory F:\googleAppEngine\helloworld\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [helloworld] in [F:\googleAppEngine\helloworld\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [F:\googleAppEngine\helloworld/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF] to [F:\googleAppEngine\helloworld\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [F:\googleAppEngine\helloworld\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [121 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: F:\googleAppEngine\helloworld\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:devserver (default-cli) < package @ helloworld <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:devserver (default-cli) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Running Development Server
[INFO] 
[INFO] Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.016 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-09T08:14:33+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/219M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:devserver (default-cli) on project helloworld: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:devserver failed. NoSuchElementException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer as it doesn't contain your code. You'll need to post your code so that people can look at it and point out where the problem is. It's preferred that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can use the "edit" button to update your question. Good luck!

Comment: I get build successful with mvn install . But when I do mvn build or mvn appengine:devserver here build get failed posted same error above . You asked code there is nothing in code its a just helloworld example.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven. From this link Testing your app with the development server this section has problem for me now.